# How I style the active tab?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a parent component(Vue) and children component.

I have a couple of  elements that switch between components by changing current data.

The problem is that I have no idea how I mark the active tabs.

I did a lot of stuff, switching between updated, beforeupdated, mounted, created, beforecreated life hooks. But nothing worked.

This code works only at the initial loading(which is "Home") I want it to only style the active one and nothing else. But it didn't work sadly.

Most of the times, it either works but styles all visited links or doesn't work at all or works at the initial active tab(like this one)

The important code's piece of the parent component:

```
<template>
  <div id="grid">
    <nav id="navbar">

      <ul id="nav">
        <a href="#" class="Home" @click="current = 'Home'" ><li>{{navbar.Home}}</li></a>        
        <a href="#" class="Reservation" @click="current = 'Reservation'" ><li>{{navbar.Reservation}}</li></a>
        <a href="#" class="About-us" @click="current = 'About-us'" ><li>{{navbar.About}}</li></a>
        <a href="#" class="Contact" @click="current = 'Contact'" ><li>{{navbar.Contact}}</li></a>
      </ul>

      <div class="button"> <!-- Make some animation of this button becomes an extendable window of singing up. Don't forget  -->
        <a href="#">Sign Up
        </a>
      </div>
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/8b/fa/5d/8bfa5d6a52a03e83b995fec69a4d8c2c.jpg" alt="" id="logo">
    </nav>      

    <main id="content"> 
      <keep-alive>
        <transition name="component-fade" mode="out-in">
          <component v-bind:is="current"></component>    
        </transition> 
      </keep-alive>          
    </main>      

    <footer>
      <p>Copyright © All Rights Reserved</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Home from "./components/Home.vue";
import Aboutus from "./components/About us.vue";
import Contact from "./components/Contact.vue";
import Reservation from "./components/Reservation.vue";
import Signup from "./components/Signup.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    Home: Home,
    "About-us": Aboutus,
    Contact: Contact,
    Reservation: Reservation,
    Signup: Signup
  },
  data() {
    return {
      navbar: {
        Home: "Home",
        Reservation: "Reservation",
        About: "About us",
        Contact: "Contact"
      },
      current: "Home"
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
    let actie = document.querySelector("." + this.current);
    actie.className = "active";
  },
  beforeUpdate: function() {
    let actie = document.querySelector("." + this.current);
    actie.className = "none";
  },
  methods: {}
};    

</script>
```

Comment: Found this fiddle, does that help you at all? https://jsfiddle.net/Herteby/kpkcfcdw/

Comment: Put v-bind:class=“current==‘Home’?’active:’’” on each li and add css for the li.active

Comment: @Nick M I totally forgot about v-bind, thank you!

Comment: @dmikester1 Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert in Vuejs, but came across one of the example in this vuejs.org site, See the CSS styles, this might be what you are looking for.

**See sample here:** https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Hope this helps

```
<h2 id="Dynamic-Components"><a href="#Dynamic-Components" class="headerlink" title="Dynamic Components"></a>Dynamic Components</h2><p>Sometimes, it’s useful to dynamically switch between components, like in a tabbed interface:</p>

<div id="dynamic-component-demo" class="demo">
  <button v-for="tab in tabs" v-bind:key="tab" class="dynamic-component-demo-tab-button" v-bind:class="{ 'dynamic-component-demo-tab-button-active': tab === currentTab }" v-on:click="currentTab = tab">
    {{ tab }}
  </button>
  <component v-bind:is="currentTabComponent" class="dynamic-component-demo-tab"></component>
</div>
<script>
Vue.component('tab-home', { template: '<div>Home component</div>' })
Vue.component('tab-posts', { template: '<div>Posts component</div>' })
Vue.component('tab-archive', { template: '<div>Archive component</div>' })
new Vue({
  el: '#dynamic-component-demo',
  data: {
    currentTab: 'Home',
    tabs: ['Home', 'Posts', 'Archive']
  },
  computed: {
    currentTabComponent: function () {
      return 'tab-' + this.currentTab.toLowerCase()
    }
  }
})
</script>
<style>
.dynamic-component-demo-tab-button {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  margin-right: -1px;
}
.dynamic-component-demo-tab-button:hover {
  background: #e0e0e0;
}
.dynamic-component-demo-tab-button-active {
  background: #e0e0e0;
}
.dynamic-component-demo-tab {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything works as expected. Problem is you are changing DOM directly and Vue have no clue you are doing it. Because Vue holds it's own, virtual DOM. So, you can try this, or read more about dynamic class binding in Vue guide:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <a
    href="#"
    class="['Home', current === 'Home' ? 'active' : '']"
    @click="current = 'Home'"
  >
    <li>{{navbar.Home}}</li>
  </a>        
  <a
    href="#"
    class="['Reservation', current === 'Reservation' ? 'active' : '']"
    @click="current = 'Reservation'"
  >
    <li>{{navbar.Reservation}}</li>
  </a>
  <a
    href="#"
    class="['About-us, current === 'About-us' ? 'active' : '']"
    @click="current = 'About-us'"
  >
    <li>{{navbar.About}}</li>
  </a>
  <a
    href="#"
    class="['Contact', current === 'Home' ? 'active' : '']"
    @click="current = 'Contact'"
  >
    <li>{{navbar.Contact}}</li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

And now just remove the mounted and beforeUpdate hooks...

PS: You should use button elements for your navigation. Due to better semantics / accessibility. Using `a` with `li` is deprecated / antipattern now.